# Run Web application as Specific user

Tags: windows, tomcat, web-applications, service

On my application server machine ,I have done drive mapping using specific user. 
But with web application running on Tomcat I am not able to access this drive because tomcat runs as a windows service and not with user which has the actual access to drive mapped. 
So i want know how to run web application on tomcat server with specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Run Tomcat as a Windows Service ( http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html ) and make sure that you set the user to run the service as isn't the standard SERVICE user or whatever.